# Linking Javadoc Page from Github

Tags: github

I have been working on Github project [Android-Commons](https://github.com/jainakhil88/android-commons). It is a collection of common Android Utilities. I have made documentation for Project code(See [here](https://github.com/jainakhil88/android-commons/tree/master/documentation)).

What I am facing issue is with I am not able to display/link Java documentation as link as see in [jBloomberg](https://github.com/assylias/jBloomberg)(click on javadoc there).

I have also linked it to [Documentation](http://jainakhil88.github.io/android-commons/#documentation) on [jainakhil88.github.io](http://jainakhil88.github.io/android-commons/)

I have already went through following articles and published the `gh-pages`, So please do not share again.

- [upload-javadoc-to-github](https://assylias.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/upload-javadoc-to-github/)
- [Stackoverflow display-javadocs-on-github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347808/display-javadocs-on-github)
- [Stackoverflow making-javadocs-available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939595/making-javadocs-available-with-github-sonatype-maven-repo)
- [ReadWrite Article on Github Pages](http://readwrite.com/2013/11/27/github-pages-explained)

To sum it up, I have following queries

- How to display Java documentation which is uploaded in Github??
- Do I need to do anything differently in `gh-pages` or elsewhere??
- Is it even possible to display Java documentation which is uploaded in Github Repo and be used as a website??

Please feel free to ask from more clarity.